# Best way to read a file into a multi-dimensional array, and skip lines that contain certain information in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I am new to Perl coding, and have come across a issue that I cannot find a away around.

I am attempting to read a file and place the information into a multi-dimensional array, this is working fine, however I have a need where certain lines in the file need to be skipped from being added to the array.

The code I am using looks like this:

```
sub read_files {
    @fields = ();
    open($input_data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";  # Open the CSV file and read its contents, if the file cannot be opened display an error and exit the program
    while (<$input_data>)  # While there is data to be read
    {
        chomp;
        push @fields, [split /\s+/];
    }
}
```

the lines in the file that I want to skip look like this:

```
121    0 -blank-                 BlockSize=2048 BlockCount=536516096 MediumType=10 Location=121/1/1 BlockAddressable=0 fsCapability=iso                     -          -          HD-WO vol1
 344    0 --bad--                 BlockSize=0 BlockCount=0 MediumType=0 Location=344/1/1 BlockAddressable=0                                                  -          -          -     icas

770    0 -XXXXX-                 -                                                                                                                          -          -          HD-WO icas
```

Vaild lines would look similar to this:

```
 753 1060 EY_icas_0416G           BlockSize=2048 BlockCount=1550534 MediumType=10 Location=753/1/1 BlockAddressable=0 PhysBlockCount=1550534 state=regular   1572740385 1793466337 HD-WO icas
 754 1061 NG_icas_0186I           BlockSize=2048 BlockCount=445776 MediumType=10 Location=754/1/1 BlockAddressable=0 PhysBlockCount=445776 state=regular     1572741506 1793391106 HD-WO icas
 755 1062 GJ_icas_0060E           BlockSize=2048 BlockCount=230419 MediumType=10 Location=755/1/1 BlockAddressable=0 PhysBlockCount=230419 state=regular     1572746004 1793444405 HD-WO icas
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Additionally when using `[split /\s+/];` to split the line read when there is a space, how can I add a comma "," to the list also ?

Comment: The lines you need to skip, how do they look?  (You didn't say that...?)  As for the question about the comma -- do you want to split on either spaces or the comma?

Comment: `/[\s,]+/`? . . .

Comment: @zdim Hi, sorry the lines that I want to skip will contain one of the following 3 words:

"-blank-" or "-XXXXX-" or "--bad--"

Comment: Then you add `next if /-(?:blank|XXXXX|-bad-)-/`; (please review for typos and/or silly errors) before `chomp`. That regex is tested against `$_` (the variable which has your line), and it matches if there is one of those three patterns in the line (`a|b|c` is either `a` or `b` or `c`), and then `next` skips the rest of that iteration.  So you skip those lines.

Comment: Note that you don't need `chomp` if you `split` on spaces the way you do. (Would need to go out of your way to make it keep that would-be trailing empty element from `split`.)

Answer (score 2):

The OP's question is not complete.

OP should specify more complete data sample with indication what lines should be *skipped*.

Following code sample is based on provided data but perhaps far from desired solution due absence of important information in the question.

For demonstration purpose in the code defined *regex* `$skip_pattern` to skip a lines starting with `#` symbol.

Empty lines also skipped as sanity check.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @data;
my $skip_pattern = qr/^#/;

while( <DATA> ) {
    next if /^\s+\z/;
    next if /$skip_pattern/;
    push @data, [split /[\s,]+/];
}

say Dumper(\@data);

exit;

__DATA__
# Sample data
121    0 -blank-                 BlockSize=2048 BlockCount=536516096 MediumType=10 Location=121/1/1 BlockAddressable=0 fsCapability=iso                     -          -          HD-WO vol1
# Line to skip
122    1 -blank-                 BlockSize=4096 BlockCount=536516096 MediumType=10 Location=121/1/1 BlockAddressable=0 fsCapability=iso                     -          -          HD-WO vol1
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '121',
            '0',
            '-blank-',
            'BlockSize=2048',
            'BlockCount=536516096',
            'MediumType=10',
            'Location=121/1/1',
            'BlockAddressable=0',
            'fsCapability=iso',
            '-',
            '-',
            'HD-WO',
            'vol1'
          ],
          [
            '122',
            '1',
            '-blank-',
            'BlockSize=4096',
            'BlockCount=536516096',
            'MediumType=10',
            'Location=121/1/1',
            'BlockAddressable=0',
            'fsCapability=iso',
            '-',
            '-',
            'HD-WO',
            'vol1'
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: Thank you using ```[split /[\s,]+/]``` worked perfectly

Comment: "_Empty lines also skipped as sanity check._"  --- should be, yes, but your code doesn't do that. The `\s+ ` requires at least one space; that's not an empty line.  Can do either `next if /^\s*\z/;` or perhaps `next if not /\S/;`

Answer (score -2):

```
open(F, "$file") or die "Could not open '$file' : $!\n";
local $/ = undef;
$_ = <F>;
close(F);

s/^(?!\d+\s+\d+\s+[\w-]+\s+(?:[\w-]+=[\w\/-]+\s+)+\d+\s+[\w-]+\s+[\w-]+\s*).*[\n\r]+//gm;

# now you have in $_ just proper formatted lines
# split them to the array as desired
```